# Creating plot in python to check total counts associated with certain threshold

Tags: python, plot

We have a table1 which has `threshold1`, `threshold2`, `threshold3`, `threshold4`. And table2 which has `id` (~100 id's), `score` data (~100k rows).

How can we create a plot where we can see how many id's belongs to certain threshold (using score data).

Input tables can be

Table1 where we have id's and thresholds:

```
|   id               | threshold1     | threshold2             | threshold3             | threshold4             |
|--------------------|----------------|------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|
|   827056812014862  |   0.05         |   0.06082916259765624  |   0.07640075683593749  |   0.10351562499999999  |
|   426654606034122  |   0.71256      |   0.7594909667968749   |   0.8388671874999999   |   0.9714794158935546   |
|   6635352627       |   0.062176484  |   0.0821764847779989   |   0.7788085937499999   |   0.9171474725008011   |
```

and Table2 where we have id's and scores (~100)

```
|   id               |   score               |
|--------------------|-----------------------|
|   827056812014862  |   0.05499883          |
|   426654606034122  |   0.73256             |
|   827056812014862  |   0.35777375          |
|   426654606034122  |   0.79949068749       |
|   827056812014862  |   0.8951301           |
|   6635352627       |   0.068176484         |
|   426654606034122  |   0.8194909667968749  |
|   6635352627       |   0.9271474725008011  |
|   827056812014862  |   0.06182916259765    |
|   827056812014862  |   0.11351562499       |
|   426654606034122  |   0.8494909667968749  |
|   827056812014862  |   0.082400756         |
|   6635352627       |   0.9371474725008011  |
```

Expected outcome can be a simple plot with id's and counts on axes.